# Debian 6.4 - Gitlab 1.2.0 - Update Gitlab 1.2.0 to 1.1.0 message

Tags: debian, git-shell

I'm setting up a Gitlab on a Debian Server 6.4

When executing this:

```
root@Gitlab:/home/git/gitlab# sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:check RAILS_ENV=production
```

Output

```
Checking Environment ...

Git configured for git user? ... yes
Has python2? ... yes
python2 is supported version? ... yes

Checking Environment ... Finished

Checking Gitlab Shell ...

GitLab Shell version? ... FAIL. Please update gitlab-shell to v1.1.0
Repo base directory exists? ... yes
Repo base directory is a symlink? ... no
Repo base owned by git:git? ... yes
Repo base access is drwxrws---? ... yes
post-receive hook up-to-date? ... yes
post-receive hooks in repos are links: ... rake aborted!
Mysql2::Error: Table 'gitlabhq_production.projects' doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM `projects`
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:245:in `query'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:245:in `block in execute'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:280:in `block in log'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:275:in `log'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:245:in `execute'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:211:in `execute'
/home/git/gitlab/config/initializers/connection_fix.rb:22:in `execute'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:259:in `execute_and_free'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:426:in `columns'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:12:in `block in initialize'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:228:in `yield'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:228:in `default'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:228:in `columns'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:248:in `column_names'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb:221:in `aggregate_column'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb:242:in `execute_simple_calculation'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb:216:in `perform_calculation'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb:159:in `calculate'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb:58:in `count'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/querying.rb:12:in `count'
/home/git/gitlab/lib/tasks/gitlab/check.rake:489:in `check_repos_post_receive_hooks_is_link'
/home/git/gitlab/lib/tasks/gitlab/check.rake:357:in `block (3 levels) in '
Tasks: TOP => gitlab:check => gitlab:gitlab_shell:check
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I'm stuck at this part:
GitLab Shell version? ... FAIL. Please update gitlab-shell to v1.1.0

Version 1.2.0 is installed. 
Could anybody help how to fix this?

I am following this guide:
https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/5-0-stable/doc/install/installation.md

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `/home/git/gitlab-shell` and change the version in the VERSION file to 1.1.0, it feels very wrong to me but it works.

I have seen that the version was updated only 3 days ago so it probably has not been fixed yet. Reckon there is code checked for explicit 1.1.0 version and the recent check in on gitlab-shell has broken this.

Hope this helps, but be on the look out for a gitlab update to support this as this fix is not ideal.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend changing the gitlab-shell version number as stated in @Noel King's answer (the correct version of gitlab-shell is 1.2.0).

**Instead, you should update `check.rake` to look for the correct version of gitlab-shell.**

To do this:

1. Edit `/home/git/gitlab/lib/tasks/gitlab/check.rake`
2. On line 640, change 
   `if gitlab_shell_version.strip == '1.1.0'` 
   to 
   `if gitlab_shell_version.strip == '1.2.0'`
3. You can also update lines 641 and 643 to reflect the correct versions in the success/error messages
4. Re-run `sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:check RAILS_ENV=production` to verify the issue is fixed

This issue has [already been corrected in the main repo](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/commit/53e54ddf8a107f02fe870159663d9763c48a3c54), but wasn't included in the 5.0 stable release.